# Applying Gaussian blur to UILabel

Tags: performance, swift, ios, cocoa

Here is the code and it is really slow, like seconds slow to render about 25 labels.

```
extension UILabel{
    func deBlur(){
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if (subview.tag == 99999) {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    func blur(){
        let  blurRadius:CGFloat = 5.1

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        blurFilter?.setDefaults()
        let imageToBlur = CIImage(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
        blurFilter?.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter?.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        let outputImage: CIImage? = blurFilter?.outputImage
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage!, from: (outputImage?.extent)!)
        layer.contents = cgimg!
    }
}
```

So this takes way too much time. For 20 labels it takes seconds on the simulator.

Comment: Is the `deBlur()` method unrelated to the `blur()`?

Comment: First of all you can draw all labels in a single context, because context creation requires memory allocation which is quite slow.

Comment: Try using EAGLContext based on GPU [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforAppleA7GPUsandLater/BestPracticesforAppleA7GPUsandLater.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH505-DontLinkElementID_1)

Comment: EAGLContext has been deprecated